# Spacemacs C++ debugging?

Tags: spacemacs, debugging, c++

What tools are you using for

- setting Breakpoints
- visualize Variables

within Spacemacs? I had a look at **gdb** but it felt awkward to set the breakpoints separated from the source files. I would like to set the breakpoints in the source file and then just run the debugger. What options do I have for achieving this?

Comment: Is `gud-gdb` good enough for you?